# is there a way to pause a script until a javascript closure is finished? JavaScript, jQuery, AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

If I use a closure to define something is there a means of waiting so to speak until the variable is populated before moving on to the next bit.

Example:

```
var myVari = someFunction();
$.each(myVari, function(){/*code for each*/});
```

the function that defines myVari is an AJAX call, which can take a second or 4 (yea its not to fast) to define the variable. Problem is, before the AJAX call yields its results the $.each has already fired off and errored due to myVari being empty. Is there a better way to approach this scenario?

Comment: I use a function as its code I would like to repurpose for various reasons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should adapt your code so that you can pass a callback to `someFunction`, which you execute when the AJAX call is completed.

The only way you can *wait* for the AJAX call to complete is to change the call to synchronous, but this is ***heavily*** discouraged as it locks up the browser completely for the duration of the AJAX call.

Because you are already using the jQuery libary, this process of `callbacks` becomes a whole lot easier. Instead of returning the variable like you are at the moment, I'd return the jQuery AJAX object ([which has a promise interface as of 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)), so you can easily add callbacks to it:

```
function someFunction () {
    return jQuery.ajax('some/url.php', {
        // whatever
    });
}

var myVari = someFunction();
myVari.done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(){/*code for each*/});
});
```

Comment: I assume .done() is actually waiting for a result based on the return of the .ajax()? I didnt know about the done() cool well thank you.

Comment: @chris: Yes, the callbacks you provide to `done()`, `fail()` and `always()` are delayed until the AJAX response has completed, and the result is available.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are trying to do, then you could try your $.each inside the 'success' handler of your ajax call.

Rewrite someFunction to something like -

```
var myVari; //define this here or in whichever calling scope where it needs to be available.
$.ajax({
    'url': 'http://..',
    'type': 'GET', // or POST
    'data': { } // whatever data you need to send
    'success': function(data) {
        myVari = process_the_server(data);
        $.each(myVari, function() {...});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a callback, like this:

```
someFunction(function(myVari) {
    $.each(myVari, function(){ /*code for each*/ });
});
```

Then redefine `someFunction` like this:

```
function someFunction(callback) {
    var myVari;

    /* ... */
    /* calcuate myVari */
    /* ... */

    /* instead of returning it, pass it to the callback: */
    callback(myVari);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The correct way is: Instead of running the `each` on its own, run it inside the ajax call.

You could, I suppose do:

```
function checkFunc() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(myVari) {
      $.each(........);
    } else {
      checkFunc();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

That not really good coding practice, but it will work.

Comment: Hey, no fair giving me a -1 - I'm perfectly aware that this is a bad thing to do.

Comment: So why suggest it when there's plenty of better ways to solve the problem?

Comment: For completion. And I did in fact suggest the better way - right at the top of the answer. But just in case the questioner can not, or will not, use that method I gave him another. It's not my business to force someone to code properly by leaving him ignorant. I perfect he code properly from knowledge.